# How to add webview scroll in an scrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent

I have a requirement to show multiple items in a list and add a WebView in the end.

I have added a RecyclerView and a WebView, and put both of them in a ScrollView.
This is working fine, but it does not shows a scroll in webview.

I need my webview to have a vertical scroll.

This is my code.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Title"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvMatchday"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <WebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:id="@+id/twitterWebView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rvMatchday" />


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Then I created a parent layout file, and added above layout in that.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

   <include layout="@layout/fragment_match"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Do you try to use the `NestedScrollView`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to use scroll view as root because recycler view and web view having their own scrolling effects. Just try with Linear as root

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvMatchday"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:id="@+id/twitterWebView"
       />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Scroll view in your  layout.xml file as well as parent layout file.
**like**

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvMatchday"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <WebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/twitterWebView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rvMatchday" />
             </LinearLayout>
```

**and parent layout**

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <include layout="@layout/fragment_match"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

on your activity/fragment, set your webview as scrollable

```
webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```